# Return data from queryForList() method - Incompatible types error

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, incompatibletypeerror

I am having trouble to get the data that I retrieve from MySQL database into a list of objects. I want to return the data and store it into the list. Once I do that, I want the data available for retrieval to a frontend framework.

But I get an incompatible type error, I cannot return the data into the list.

**Note:** I am relatively new to Spring-Boot and JdbcTemplate.

**My code**

This is inside my rest controller

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate temp;

@RequestMapping("/foo")
public List<Foo> connectAndRetrieve() {

    String sql = "SELECT fooName FROM Foo;";

    // Error Here
    List<Foo> data = temp.queryForList(sql, Foo.class);

    return data;
}
```

How do I return the data from the method and use that data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually projecting `fooName` instead of `Foo`, try the following:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate temp;

@RequestMapping("/foo")
public List<Foo> connectAndRetrieve() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Foo";
    return temp.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Foo.class));
}
```

Here you can find the documentation for [BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html)